# Запятая в заглавии

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как, заголовок

Есть заглавие текста: «О том как нужно писать».

Нужна ли запятая перед "как"?

Answer (score 2):

Нужна, ведь ***как нужно писать***-придаточное предложение, оно отделяется запятой.

Answer (score 1):

Союз **[как](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_183)** соединяет части сложноподчиненного предложения (первая часть — неполное предложение, без подлежащего и сказуемого). И здесь неважно, заголовок это или отдельное предложение в каком-то тексте, — запятая перед «как» необходима.

Вот классические примеры:

**О том, как я учился писать** ([**статья**](http://gorkiy-lit.ru/gorkiy/articles/article-351.htm) М. Горького);
**О том, как гном покинул дом и...** (мультфильм, 1976);
**О том, как буря перевесила вывески** ([**сказка**](http://andersen.com.ua/ru_o_tom_kak_burya_perevesila_vyveski.html) Андерсена).

***О том, как хороша природа,***
Не часто говорит народ
Под этой синью небосвода,
Над этой бледной синью вод.
С. Маршак

*Повесть **о том, как** поссорился Иван Иванович с Иваном Никифоровичем* (Гоголь);
*Повесть **о том, как** один мужик двух генералов прокормил* (Салтыков-Щедрин).